# ¿La forma correcta de hacer una petición get() para obtener el JSON del controlador del API de Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, api, aplicación-web, codeigniter-3

**Buenas, he estado haciendo varios intentos fallidos y mirado varios tutoriales, he añadido los archivos indicados a mi proyecto, pero no consigo obtener el JSON del controlador del API en postman. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?**

**Código del controlador del API**

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

// This can be removed if you use __autoload() in config.php OR use Modular Extensions
/** @noinspection PhpIncludeInspection */
require APPPATH . '/libraries/REST_Controller.php';

// use namespace
use Restserver\Libraries\REST_Controller;

/**
 * This is an example of a few basic user interaction methods you could use
 * all done with a hardcoded array
 *
 * @package         CodeIgniter
 * @subpackage      Rest Server
 * @category        Controller
 * @author          Phil Sturgeon, Chris Kacerguis
 * @license         MIT
 * @link            https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver
 */
class cursosapi extends REST_Controller {

    public function lista_cursos_get() {
        $this->load->model('cursos_model');
        $cursos_array = $this->cursos_model->get_lista_cursos();

        // La siguiente línea de código devuelvo en formato
        // JSON el listado de estudiantes de la base de datos_cuerpo
        // dando como código de respuesta 200
        $this->set_response($cursos_array, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
    }
```

**Petición en postman**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**La página que lanza**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>¡Acceso prohibido!</title>
        <link rev="made" href="mailto:postmaster@localhost" />
        <style type="text/css">
            <!--/*-->
            <![CDATA[/*>
            <!--*/ 
    body { color: #000000; background-color: #FFFFFF; }
    a:link { color: #0000CC; }
    p, address {margin-left: 3em;}
    span {font-size: smaller;}
/*]]>*/-->
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/4FF13B75-E934-4941-B4F8-E509B9702BFE/main.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>¡Acceso prohibido!</h1>
        <p>




      Usted no tiene permiso para acceder al objeto solicitado.
      El objeto está protegido contra lectura o
      el servidor no puede leerlo.



</p>
        <p>
Si usted cree que esto es un error del servidor, por favor comuníqueselo al

            <a href="mailto:postmaster@localhost">administrador
del portal</a>.
        </p>
        <h2>Error 403</h2>
        <address>
            <a href="/">localhost</a>
            <br />
            <span>Apache/2.4.25 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/5.6.30</span>
        </address>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solucionado, la petición se escribía:**

```
http://localhost/classroom_manager/api/v0/cursosapi/cursos
```

y también había que importar las librerías del idioma, inglés y español.